# How to change Datetime format in a DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am stucked about datagridview control in which i need to type datetime format in a cell like my own format i need.

I want from the client to enter datetime like "mm/dd" and hit enter, then this field will be seen as a short datetime format.

For example: Client will write "06/27" and hit enter. In cell, it will show 06/27/2015. (The year that we are in). Why i need is that, i will be able to send data in a format that in SQL server accepts.

Should i need also to use it with datetimepicker control or without it i can also handle it?

Comment: You are mixing things up. A date has a value which is what you save and/or export. It also has a format used for display; and it can be applied another format for writing SQL strings. For export, however, do use a parameterized approach where you supply the date value as is. You can Bing/Google on all these subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really need to change the value of cell you can use dataGridView_CellEndEdit event and then access cell with:

```
var cell = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```